# Initializing vector with reference_wrapper's locally

Tags: c++, polymorphism, containers, reference-wrapper

I have a number of inheritance-related types that I want to use from standard container (`std::reference_wrapper` is a proper value type for such a container, AFAIU). However, I do not understand, how to initialize such a container when the values, the references to which are inserted in a map, are not global variables. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct I
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct S1: public I
{
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "S1 " << i << endl;
    }
    int i{};
};

struct S2: public I
{
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "S2 " << f << endl;
    }
    float f{};
};

std::vector<reference_wrapper<I>> v;

void init()
{
    S1 x{};
    S2 y{};
    v.emplace_back(x);
    v.emplace_back(y);
}

int main()
{
    init();
    v[1].get().print();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but I get some memory corruption at run-time. What is a proper way of initializing container of `std::reference_wrapper`s?

Comment: If you need `v` to own the instances you store within, you need it to be an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<I>>` and use dynamic allocation through `std::make_unique<I>()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a reference to a function local object.  Once the function exits those local objects are destroyed and you are left with dangling references in the vector.  What you can do to fix this is to switch to using a `std::unique_ptr<I>` and `std::make_unique` which dynamically allocates the objects you want to store in the vector.  The `std::unique_ptr` will manage the memory and once the vector is destroyed it will destroy the `std::unique_ptr`'s that are in the vector and they will in turn delete the memory that was acquired to hold the objects.  That would give you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct I
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct S1: public I
{
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "S1 " << i << endl;
    }
    int i{};
};

struct S2: public I
{
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "S2 " << f << endl;
    }
    float f{};
};

std::vector<unique_ptr<I>> v;

void init()
{
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<S1>()); // creates a defaulted S1 in the unique_ptr
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<S2>()); // creates a defaulted S2 in the unique_ptr
}

int main()
{
    init();
    v[1]->print(); // or (*v[1]).print()
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that your objects `S1 x` and `S2 y` are destroyed at the end of your `init` function. So, at the end of `init()`, your vector `v` contains references to nothing. Therefore, when trying to call `print()`, you get a `segmentation fault`.

In a similar way, consider this code:

```
int& get_i()
{
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_i() << std::endl; // segmentation fault
    return 0;
}
```

This as well produces a `segmentation fault` as `get_i()` returns a reference to a local variable (which gets destroyed at the end if `get_i()`).

You could user `std::unique_ptr` instead as mentioned in one of the comments.